# default selected row color in kendo grid doesn't effect

Tags: jquery, row, kendo-grid, selectable

Am setting the row background color Ondatabound event based on some condition

```
               $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').css("background-color", "green");
```

when the row is selected the default row selection color doesn't appear, the above new style is overriding the default behavior. Even when i explicitly set the row color on

```
    .k-grid table tr.k-state-selected
    {
     background: #22B99F;
     border-color:#22B99F;
    }
```

the above doesn't effect. When user clicked on the row want change the row color to above what is the best way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
 $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').addClass("green-row")
```

and add new css

```
.green-row td{
    background: green!important;
}
```